# is there a way to see which files include/require other files?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm currently working with [Active Collab](http://www.activecollab.com/), which is built following the MVC programming architecture, meaning a lot of files including/requiring a lot of other files. The system is pretty big and i need to do some reverse engineering as i am looking for some specific functions.

**Is there a way to see in logs or any other way to know which files include others files and in what order?**

**UPDATE**

I did use get_included_files(), which answers my question, but i ended up with an array of over 100 filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find out what files are included is to use [get_included_files()/get_required_files()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php)

E.G:

```
// This file is abc.php
include 'test1.php';
include_once 'test2.php';
require 'test3.php';
require_once 'test4.php';

$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
```

would give you:

```
abc.php
test1.php
test2.php
test3.php
test4.php
```

Comment: Thanks! i will check this out, and if there is not a simpler way (this will require that i modify several files) mark as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you have an IDE of some sort (I'm thinking about PHPStorm) - it will index all of your files, and you can simply ctrl-click a function call anywhere, and it will go to the file/location where the function is being defined...

I don't use PHPStorm anymore, but I wish Notepad++ added that feature!

Comment: thanks for the tip, i used notepad++ for a while it is a nice editor